# Read of memory allocation returns spurious results if, following read, free() is called - why does this happen? (embedded)

Tags: memory, optimization, embedded, realloc, stm32f4discovery

Programming on a stm32f4 some strange behaviour is observed:

1. Data is allocated using realloc, which is called every second or so, as such; `ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof)`
2. Values are read into the data - it has been confirmed that: A) The indexing of the array is correct and B) Immediately following each read of values into memory the array holds the correct values.

Upon reading the array the code fails to produce proper output (outputs 0s the vast majority of the time) if `free(ptr)` is called in any code following the read. When `free(ptr)` is not called the code functions properly. It seems that the sequential nature of C breaks down in this instance?

Immediately following each read of values into memory the array holds the correct values regardless of any 'free' calls. Realloc is used because this interrupt is called repeatedly. The 'random pointer' has been set to NULL when initialised, before the pointer is realloced. This is an embedded program on a stm32f4.

Being inexperienced with embedded c I can only speculate, but imagine the cause may be faulty optimisation?

Is this behaviour known? I am aware that it is best practice to avoid malloc ect but due to the large variances in amounts of data potentially being held in this application the flexibility is required.

The code mallocs using pointers contained within a global struct. The following code is the offending material:

```
structContainingMemoryPointer storedData;
numberOfInts = 0;

    // ***********Getdata if interrupt conditions state to do so - contained within  interrupt***********
interrupt {
    if (SpecificInterrupt) {
    numberOfInts++;
    storedData.Arrayptr =
        realloc(storedData.Arrayptr,
            sizeof(int) * storedData.numberOfInts * 2);

    // Store the value of actualTemp
    storedData.Arrayptr[storedData.numberOfInts - 1] = actualTemp;
    // Step through the temperature values array and send to USART 
    for (arrayStep = 0; arrayStep < storedData.numberOfTempAllocations;
         arrayStep++) {
        // Convert to string and send
        sprintf(valueString, ":%d", storedData.temperature[arrayStep]);
        USART_puts(USART2, valueString);
    }

    }

    // ***********free memory*************
    free(storedDataStruct.Arrayptr);
    storedDataStruct.Arrayptr = NULL;
    // End of program, no return from this point to previous points.
```

Comment: Please post the actual code in question.  It will be much easier for us to provide help that way.

Comment: I will attempt to grab the most relevant bits of code now, thank you for the reply.

Comment: Why are you allocating using realloc? Realloc is expecting a pointer that you have previously allocated using malloc/calloc. I'm not sure what it will do if you just give it some random pointer.

Comment: What is the OS used? What is the `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` provider?

Comment: Realloc is used because this interrupt is called repeatedly. The 'random pointer' has been set to NULL when initialised. This is an embedded program on a stm32f4.

Comment: `realloc` and `sprintf` inside an interrupt? No good idea... and `USART_puts` too.

Comment: It's not clear where your free() is called in relation to where the interrupt may be happening.  It's plausible that those instructions are being reordered and are executing before you'd want them to be.  But as others note, there's a lot of bad practice in the code, with significant work being done at the interrupt level...

Comment: malloc, realloc, and free on a microcontroller?!

Comment: [See this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581) for an explanation of why you shouldn't use malloc in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you set `storedData.numberOfInts` to zero after calling `free(storedDataStruct.Arrayptr);`? You've disposed of the array, the count should be reset.